# Equivalent to ResultSet.getRow() in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, resultset, row-number

JavaDoc

> int getRow() throws SQLException
>
> Retrieves the current row number. The first row is number 1, the
>   second number 2, and so on.

Is there anything similar to `getRow()` in Hibernate?

**[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow())**

Comment: Not sure what you want. The ieration of the ResultSet rows is abstract by hibernate. Do you need to navigate on your own for each result row or whats the use case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything similar to getRow() in Hibernate?

Yes there's , you can use Hibernate **[ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html)** and [.getRowNumber()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html#getRowNumber()) method which returns the current row number from the results.

> **getRowNumber()**
> throws HibernateException
>
> Get the current location in the result set. The first row is number 0,
> contrary to JDBC.

**Note:**

Keep in mind that the difference is that row numbers in hibernate result set begins from 0.

Comment: I didn't say I want to access row at particular position I want row number.

Comment: "Hibernate result set begins from 0." So I don't want this. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: You can simply add +1 to it so use `.getRowNumber()+1` and you will have the same thing as in JDBC

Comment: I want Hibernate to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you extract a `List`, the row number is the element index in the List:

```
List<Author> authors = (List<Author>) session
    .createQuery("select a from Author a where a.fullName = :fullName")
    .setParameter("fullName", fullName)
    .list();
```

and the row number is just the index:

```
for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < authors.size(); rowNumber++) {
    Author author = authors.get(rowNumber);
}
```